# Update SharePoint Group Owner

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, pnp, spgroup, pnp-js-core

I'm trying to update the Owner of a SP Group. This is what I've tried:

```
import pnp from "pnp";

let newgroup = {};
pnp.sp.web.siteGroups.getByName("BA_Actuarial").get().then(function(g) {
    newgroup = g
})

let group  = pnp.sp.web.siteGroups.getByName("BA_SargonTest").expand("owner")

group.get().then(data => {
    console.log(data, newgroup)
    group.update({
        Owner: newgroup
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible using REST API's itself. So, using PnP JS core also, it wont be possible, as its a wrapper of SP REST APIs.

User voice - [Add the possibility to set the Owner when creating a SharePoint Group using REST API](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/11503626-add-the-possibility-to-set-the-owner-when-creating)

Mark Anderson's blog - [Capture missing SP REST API endpoints](http://sympmarc.com/2017/05/17/lets-capture-missing-or-insufficient-sharepoint-rest-endpoints/comment-page-2/)

Workaround using the old `_vti_bin/client.svc` looks like possible (haven't tested).

[Set group owner using REST API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2dcf6e49-cff8-403b-b52e-04d240bef16d/set-group-owner-using-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using information from the following article: https://www.sharepointeurope.com/set-a-sharepoint-group-owner-with-power-automate/

The request below works to add an existing 'SharePoint group' as the owner of another (newly created) SharePoint group within a SharePoint Communication Site:
[image]